# Access subfolder in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a container that installs one of my apps.

In this application, I have to do a `composer install` at the root but also in a sub-folder.

In my dockerfile I do this:

```
# Switch to non-root 'app' user & install app dependencies
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN chown -R $NON_ROOT_USER:$NON_ROOT_GROUP $LARAVEL_PATH
USER $NON_ROOT_USER
# Install composer in base directoru
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-dev --no-autoloader
# Here I want to go to subfolder
RUN ls -la
RUN cd ./web/app/themes/sage
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-dev --no-autoloader
RUN rm -rf /home/$NON_ROOT_USER/.composer
```

The problem is, I'm getting the following error:
`can't cd to ./web/app/themes/sage: No such file or directory`

However, when I look at the build, I do `RUN ls -la` and see the correct file architecture with my existing "web" folder.

How to do ?

Comment: Either change the `WORKDIR` before running your commands or issue all your commands related to composer in one single `RUN` stanza (i.e. separate each command with `&&`). As is you cd command on its own is just useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WORKDIR` to change working directory. So replace `RUN cd ./web/app/themes/sage` with `WORKDIR /web/app/themes/sage`